# What is this singing style called?

Tags: voice, history, styles

I've been scouring google for over an hour, but I'm at a loss as to how to search apparently.

I'd like to know what the singing style used here is called. I've tried looking for Balkan vocal styles, eastern singing styles etc, but the closest i find is "turbo-folk" which is clearly not about the singing.

Obviously it's the "vibrato" style of his singing. I've heard it before in lots of Balkans based music (Greek, Serbian etc) but also in muslim cultures like Bosnia and further into the middle east/Turkey.

I'm curious where that style of singing comes from, what it's known as etc.

[edit] The post mentioned in the comments does not answer the question,- the question is similar, but no answer was given to the actual name of this style.
Is there none ?

Comment: Unfortunately, identification of styles or elements is off topic here. We are more focused on questions like how to sing in a given style and how to interpret the melodies and/or harmonies used in a certain style.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would seem to lie more in the realms of ornamentation, rather than vibrato. The technique would just about be covered by trills, turns and/or mordents, although microtonal movement may need to be addressed.Let's not forget Indian and flamenco music either. Perhaps you could go to a related site that deals with a language, say Spanish or Macedonian, and ask if they have a term for the technique.